# Terminate Service that has been started by another Service (Kernel-Level)

Tags: c++, winapi

I've got a problem: 
There's a process that starts a service, let's call it service_A, which then starts another service, service_B.
I need to disable this service_B as it restrains my system / program.

What I do for now is hooking the process and prevent the start of service_A -> service_B won't get started.

Now I need a solution for the case when I start the process without doing a hook -> service_B gets started and that is done by service_A so I assume it's on some kind of kernel level?
Are there any ways to do that via the WinAPI? 
Things I can access: Everything a normal application can access + grab the handle of the SC Manager that is owned by the process I'm targeting.

Thanks for any help / advice

Comment: Are you running as an administrator? What do you mean by "handle of the SC manager" do you mean handle to the SC manager process itself, handle created with `OpenSCManager` or what? What is "the process you are targeting" - do you mean the service_A process?

Comment: Yes, I'm running as an administrator.
Yes, the handle created with OpenSCManager by the process that launches service_A
The process I'm targeting is a process that creates the service_A service via CreateService / StartService

Answer (score 1):

OK the scenario is:

- You are running as administrator.
- You start Process1, and you are able to control it's execution environment, inject threads etc, and use the debugging APIs.
- Process1 starts Service_A using the SCM
- Service_A starts Service_B using the SCM

Given that you have control of Process1, can you leverage that to prevent Service_A starting Service_B?

The answer is: You don't need to do this. You are running as administrator! You control the whole machine! Either

- disable Service_B using `ChangeServiceConfig`
- change the service_B executable to one you control, which just stops itself immediately (using the same API)

So specifically:

When Process1 attempts to start the service you intercept this call. You change the definition of Service_B to be a do-nothing service, which just waits a few seconds and resets the service definition back to what it was, then quits. Then you allow Process1 to continue. It starts Service_A, which in turn starts your changed Service_B. Your changed Service_B puts the service definition back to what it was, then quits. In the meantime, you now know which process hosts Service_A so you can inject code into that service to prevent it starting Service_B again.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds pretty good!
So far I have this code:
`ChangeServiceConfigA(serviceHandle, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, SERVICE_DISABLED, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);`

That should only disable the service, shouldn't it?

Comment: Hm, I can't edit my comment.
ControlService is able to stop services. Problem: I get "ERROR_INVALID_SERVICE_CONTROL" returned. That means the handle either is invalid (it isn't, I get information about the service in the returned structure) or it is unacceptable to the service. I guess that's my problem and has to do with the fact that the driver has been started on a kernel level, right? How can I get the necessary access rights?

Comment: @Nicolai, so your service is actually a device driver? You can find out what controls the service can accept using QueryServiceStatusEx. If the flag SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP is not set in the dwControlsAccepted member you cannot stop the service.

Comment: Also it looks like you are trying to disable an antivirus. Are you writing malware?

Comment: No, I'm not writing any malware and I don't want to disable an antivrus. I don't even have enough knowledge for that.
I'll take a look into QueryServiceStatusEx, thanks.

Comment: Oh, update: dwControlsAccepted is set to 0 so I don't have any rights. :/ any other possibilities?

Comment: @Nicolai, you may be suffering the X/Y problem. What are you trying to achieve by disabling the driver? What is the ultimate goal behind "I need to disable this service_B as it restrains my system / program"? Can you solve THAT problem in another way, e.g. by solving the problem while COMPLYING with the restraint?

Comment: Well, the driver prevents me from accessing a process. I need to access that process. The way I'm solving the problem is preventing the first driver (service_A) to launch, but as soon as I start the program without preventing the launch of service_A, I'm in trouble as service_B has started then. Now I want to fix that in another way that doesn't force me to reboot my system before I can access the program again. I don't think that there's another solution than disabling the driver..

Comment: @nicolai, What process does the driver prevent you from accessing? Why do you need to access it? Why is the driver preventing you (what is the developer's motivation)? How is it preventing you? What problem are you trying to solve by accessing that process in the first place? Can you solve that problem some other way without accessing the process?